# Chrome removing context from referrer upon navigation

Tags: google-chrome, browser, navigation, referrer, referrer-policy

I have two web applications http://localhost:8090/app1, http://localhost:8099/app2. User gets redirected from app1 to app2 in one case.

Upon redirection app2 gets referrer as http://localhost:8090/ by excluding context name app1 . It is happening only in chrome since version 78. I am suspecting that it has been happening because of [this fix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998284).

Is there any way to tackle this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing this today as well. What I found is that Chrome is in the process of changing how referrers are handled in cross-domain contexts (i.e localhost to another URL).
Read more about that here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default

Within that blog post, they show how to change the behavior back to how it used to be. That can be done by setting the "Reduce default 'referer' header granularity." Chrome Flag to "Disabled". Go here to do that: chrome://flags/#reduced-referrer-granularity